# How to use virtual DNS to lookup for VMs?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, qemu, virtual-network

I have multiple qemu VMs dinamically rebooted. Each of them with DHCP in a NAT virtual network and a unique hostname. From any VM I can see that resolv.conf is using 192.168.122.1 as nameserver.

I want to access a VM using hostname instead of setting a static IP configuration in each of them.

My virtual network is 192.168.122.* and I can list the interface in my host:

```
$ ip addr
...
4: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:a4:49:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:40:7f:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
...
```

Adding nameserver 192.168.122.1 to /etc/resolv.conf is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Adding nameserver 192.168.122.1 to /etc/resolv.conf at the beginning solves the problem, but faces another: every time that host is rebooted, NetworkManager rewrites the resolv.conf file.